# Registry key is not being created upon install using a c# msi installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using the Visual Studio Registry Editor to create my c# installer. I am trying to write a registry key upon installing. I add the key "HKLM\Software\HTMLBuilder". I install my app but the key never gets created. After searching the googles and trying different things, I can not get the key created. Below is a screenshot of the properties I currently have set in visual studio 2010.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\HTMLBuilder` registry key?

Answer (score 0):

Steve had the answer to my question. It was put under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\HTMLBuilder. THANK YOU!